# Following StackAbuse guide but it isn't working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following [this](https://stackabuse.com/text-generation-with-python-and-tensorflow-keras/) guide on a rnn text generating network using tensorflow and numpy. I have been following the guide almost word for word but it has encountered an error on 23 and 26 due to a "TypeError: can only join an interable". I'm not sure what that could mean as I have been pretty much copying the guide. Anyone have an idea as to what the problem could be?
code:

```
import numpy
import sys
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

file = open("C:/Users/alpha/Desktop/coding/pickles.txt").read()


def tokenizeWords(input):
    # lowercase everything to standardize
    input = input.lower()

    # instantiate the tokenizer
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(input)

    # if the created token isn't in the stop words, make it part of "filtered"
    filtered = filter(lambda token: token not in stopwords.words('english'), tokens)
    return "".join(filter)


processed_inputs = tokenizeWords(file)

chars = sorted(list(set(processed_inputs)))
char_to_num = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
input_len = len(processed_inputs)
vocab_len = len(chars)
print("Total number of characters", input_len)
print("Total vocab", vocab_len)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says that `join()` method requires an iterable such as `list` etc. but you are passing `filter()` method, which is incorrect. The line

```
return "".join(filter)
```

is incorrect. You want to use the filtered list and not the `filter` method

```
return "".join(filtered)
```

Comment: of course my downfall is a typo, Thank you! I didn't catch that in the difference checker

Comment: Glad, I could help. Please mark the answer as correct so that someone else can benefit from the answer

Comment: Actually, this question should be closed since it was caused by a typo and it is unlikely that anybody else will benefit from this.